# Putting titles on markers on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have problems on adding titles on each marker, any idea on how to add those titles on each marker?

```
<div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
```

below are the codes for the marker

```
      ['SM North Edsa', 14.65696, 121.03017, 1],
      ['SM Mall of Asia', 14.53502, 120.98348, 2],
      ['SM Megamall', 14.58392, 121.05690, 3],
      ['Trinoma', 14.65353, 121.03322, 4],
      ['SM The Annex', 14.65687, 121.02683, 5],
      ['Gateway', 14.62276, 121.05374, 6],
      ['SM Iloilo', 10.71415, 122.55109, 7],

    ];
```

and here is the rest of the code of the whole webpage.

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.59175, 120.98295),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
       }
      </script>+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map, 
    title: locations[i][0]
  });
```

Refer to [this tutorial](http://theoryapp.com/google-maps-with-multiple-markers-and-infowindow/).